# How to unlist automation friend lists in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friends, list, automation

In my Facerbook friend list, there are some lists that were created automatically (the one with lightning icon on their right) e.g. the lists whose names are my high school and undergraduate university.

I don't want to see those list when enlisting my friends into a new list.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself by going [here](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists) and archive the list(s) we don't want.